# Add touch events to VrPanoramaView class of google cardboard SDK for android

Tags: android, touch, google-cardboard, panoramas

I am working on a panorama app. I am using VrPanoramaView class of google cardboard SDK to view panorama in my app. VrPanoramaView class provides gyro navigation to view panorama. Is it possible to attach touch events along with gyro navigation to the panorama.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now Google Cardboard SDK is deprecated and Google VR SDK is available [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/).

SDK has VrPanoramaView class for displaying 360 degree panorama images.

You can set touch event on it.